# How to fetch data from database using ASP.net MVC?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

---

This is my view.

```html
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="font-size:13.9px;font-family:'Segoe UI';">
            <div>

                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" style="padding:0px;padding-top:10px">
                    <li role="presentation" class="activeIndex"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" >EventLog</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">ApplicationLog</a></li>
                    
                </ul>

                <!-- Tab panes -->
                <div class="tab-content" style="padding-top:15px">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                        <table class="table table-striped ">
                            <thead style="background-color: rgba(7,45,120,.8); color: white; font-size: initial;">
                                <tr>

                                    <th>EventLogID</th>
                                    <th>UserName</th>
                                    <th>Message</th>
                                    <th>Severity</th>
                                    <th>Type</th>
                                    <th>StackTrace</th>
                                    <th>PageSource</th>
                                    <th>CreatedDttm</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead style="background-color: rgba(7,45,120,.8); color: white; font-size: initial">
                                <tr>

                                    <th>EventLogID</th>
                                    <th>UserName</th>
                                    <th>UserValidationMessage</th>
                                    <th>DetailedMessage</th>
                                    <th>LogInTime</th>
                                    <th>LogOutTime</th>
                                    <th>CreatedDttm</th>


                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                        </table>



                    

            </div>
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

I have created a view in mvc by creating a table.My aim is to populate the table with the data in the sql database.My Controller looks something like this

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    OnlineModel model = new OnlineModel();
     var result = model.GetAdminData();
    return View();
}
```

And in model I don't know how to use the LINQ to SQL query

```
public string GetAdminData()
{
    var result = ((from eng in odsEntities.EventLogs select eng.EventLogID).Distinct().ToList());
    return "";
}
```

But I don't know how to do the remaining steps. Is the code written in model correct ?

Comment: is your view strongly typed with the model?

Comment: No it's not strongly typed @Katana

Comment: I looked an article for you http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/displaying-a-table-of-database-data-cs take time to read. For less complexity make your view strongly typed so you have access of the model in your view.

Comment: Thanks @Katana I need some clarification on LINQ to SQL

Comment: First you query is creating `List<int>` (assuming `EventLogID` is type of `int` so there for the method needs to be `public List<int> GetAdminData()` (not `string`) and its `return result;` Then the controller method needs to be return something to the view. But you have created a `OnlineModel` and then just throw it away, and you have created a `List<int>` and throw that away as well so its not clear what you want to return to the view.

Comment: If you have a time for learning look at this video for creating asp.net MVC app from scratch. It is not in English, but visual contects can help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJkqgc0dkU8

Comment: see the edit in my question.I have shown the view @StephenMuecke

Comment: @rva.raghav, That does not help at all. What model to you want to pass to the view, and what do you want to display in the view that relates to that model.

Comment: @rva.raghav, I see you know nothing about MVC pattern, you must read about its. Without basic knowledge nobody can help you.

Comment: To put it in simple words,I have created tabs and by clicking the tabs it will show a table containing only fields.Now I want to display the contents of the fields by retrieving data from the database.So how should I do that by bringing the data from the database to the view? @StephenMuecke

Comment: I have a basic knowledge on mvc pattern @ElvinMammadov . could you try to help me in this case ?

Comment: @rva.raghav, You need to go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics of MVC. No one can help you based on what is in your question (none of the code even makes sense)

Comment: I have undeleted it @ElvinMammadov

Comment: The remaining steps... That's setting up a complete data access layer. A little bit too broad.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must send this data to the view. Change your index action as follow

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
     OnlineModel model = new OnlineModel();
     var result = model.GetAdminData();
     return View(result);
   }
   ```
2. And modified your view for getting this data.

   ```
   @model IEnumerable<EventLog>// write it to head of page Perhaps you need to add true namespace for Eventlog class
   // then write it inside table
   <tbody>
       @foreach (item in Model)
       {
           <tr>
               <td>@item.EventLogID</td>
               <td>@item.UserName</td>
               <td>@item.Message</td>
               <td>@item.Severity</td>
               <td>@item.Type</td>
               <td>@item.StackTrace</td>
               <td>@item.PageSource</td>
               <td>@item.CreatedDttm</td>
           </tr>
       }
   </tbody>
   ```